# Get screen size in pixels in windows form in C#

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve the Screen Resolution from a C# winform app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402739/how-to-retrieve-the-screen-resolution-from-a-c-sharp-winform-app)

How can I get the screen size in Windows forms?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402739/how-to-retrieve-the-screen-resolution-from-a-c-sharp-winform-app

Comment: [This has both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254197/how-can-i-get-the-active-screen-dimensions) the WinForms and WPF solution

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Check the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class and its property Bounds

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
```

Comment: CAUTION: On a MULTIPLE MONITOR system, what you might instead want to know is the size of the screen THAT A SPECIFIC FORM is on. For this, use Screen.FromControl(myForm). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402739/how-to-retrieve-the-screen-resolution-from-a-c-sharp-winform-app for more details.

Comment: for multiple screen system. one could get the the screen that holds the largest portion of the main form from the app's main form like:

 Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;

Comment: Caution number 2: This won't work on 64 bit mono on macos (because winforms is not implemented for 64bit yet). I just tripped on this.