# Getting the width of the form C#

Tags: c#, forms, window, width

I have set my form to be full screen and trying to get the `width` and the `height` as an integer. I have been looking for the past hour but can't seem to get an answer. In Java its a simple `JFrame.getwidth();` but no so simple for c#?

using windows forms

Comment: So your form is now full screen and you want to know how wide it is correct? Surely that is just `Width` / `this.Width`

Comment: no that doesn't seem to work I'm trying to set a few images the same width as my form and using that somehow is making it smaller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) can help you to get the size.

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
```

You can also have a look on [How to retrieve the Screen Resolution from a C# winform app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402789/3796048)