# Decrease control height from the top

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to decrease the `ToolStripDropDown` height from Top? I have a custom control that show a list of data when typing on it, the behavior is like `TextBox` with `AutoCompleteMode.Suggest`. When you type on it, the list will show and the `ToolStripDown` is decreasing height. This control used to search/filter data from Database. Then user can select it by clicking on the items or just press enter.

The problem is when the `ToolStripDropDown` reached the bottom of the screen, it overlaps the control use to input the text.

I want something like the `ComboBox` when the list reaches the bottom of screen, it display the list at the top. So for the control I am working, it will show the List at the top of the `TextBox` then decrease the `ToolStripDropDown` height so it will goes close to the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402789/1623971) written by [Paul Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27968/paul-williams) to get the current screen size. Then figure out where you need to redraw the dropdown from the top by getting the Height of the Dropdown using `ToolStripDropDown.Size` and `ToolStripDropDown.Location`

```
Form myForm;
Screen myScreen = Screen.FromControl(myForm);
Rectangle area = myScreen.WorkingArea
```