# Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows

I need to list all the screens on my Windows PC, not only the main display or current screen.
The reason; I would like my user to be able to display a message window on a screen of their choice and not only on the main screen.
The below code works, but it's not enough for what I'm trying to do.
Any ideas on how to detect all the screens, please?

```
    var h = Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height.ToString();
        var w = Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width.ToString();
```

I tried traversing the structure of libraries in search of the multi display option or the option to detect the screen but nothing like that seems to be available.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402789/7462031

Comment: @FreakyAli, that is for Windows Forms (winforms). Do you have a similar link for Windows Desktop App SDK?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, have you found it since?